# Create AWS lambda function in Java responding to AWS Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have created a chatbot using AWS Lex however I want to create AWS lambda function in java as 'initialization and validation code hook' to validate the user input and respond to him accrodingly.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `lambda`, for blueprint select `blank function`, then select the Java 8 runtime.

There are no sample blueprints in Java so you will have to create the function yourself.

Comment: I know that I have to create my handlers in JAVA. Is there any template for java project that I can start writing my code?

Comment: No, there are no sample blueprints in Java. You'll have to look at the templates that are in other languages and convert them to Java.